Is the complement of a degree 2 divisor in $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ an algebraic torus?
Let $K$ be a field, and let $D\subset\mathbb{P}^1_K$ be an effective divisor of degree 2, defined over $K$. The complement $C := \mathbb{P}^1_K - D$ is thus a smooth curve over $K$, which over the splitting field of $D$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_{m,K}$. If $D$ is not split (i.e., it consists of a single point whose residue field is quadratic over $K$), does $C$ still have the structure of an algebraic torus? I want to say that it is a twisted form of $\mathbb{G}_{m,K}$, but I'm not sure. Is this true? Is there a "high level" way to see this?
At a more concrete level, one can try to define a group law on $C$ as follows: Let $f : C_{\overline{K}}\rightarrow\mathbb{G}_{m,\overline{K}}$ be an isomorphism which sends a $K$-rational point to the origin. Then for $x,y\in C(\overline{K})$, define the product $m(x,y) = f^{-1}(f(x)\cdot f(y))$, where "$\cdot$" is the product in $\mathbb{G}_{m,\overline{K}}(\overline{K})$. How do we see that the morphism $m : C_{\overline{K}}\times C_{\overline{K}}\rightarrow C_{\overline{K}}$ is defined over $K$?

Your product $m$ has as its identity $f^{-1}(e)$ where $e \in \mathbb{G}_{m, \overline{K}}$ is the identity, so if this point isn't $K$-rational then $m$ can't be defined over $K$.

@QiaochuYuan That's a good point. I've added the condition that $f^{-1}(e)$ is $K$-rational.
